# Remove element from array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've been making a phonebook in C but I have problem with the deleting option.

For example, my phonebook consist of

1. Add a name
2. show names
3. remove name (this omitting the other options like phone number, adress, etc.)

When I remove a contact using the 3<sup>rd</sup> option and I go to the 2<sup>nd</sup>, a list with the names that I have saved is shown but **without the name that I've deleted**. But this repeats me the last position.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

char name[5][20];
char aux[20];
int position;
int op;


void menu();
void add();
void show();
void show_remove();
//void remove();
void pause();


int main() 
{
menu(); 

return 0;
}


void menu()
{
do{

system("clear");

printf("\tMAIN MENU\n\n");

printf("Choose one of the next options: \n\n");

printf("1.....Add a name\n");
printf("2.....Show the names in the register\n");
printf("3.....Delete a name on the register\n");
printf("4.....Exit\n");
printf("Choose your option: ");
scanf(" %i", &op);  

system("clear");

switch(op)
{
    case 1:
    add();
    break;

    case 2:
    show();
    break;

    case 3:
    show_remove();
    break;

    case 4:
    printf("\nEnd of the program");
    pause();

    }


    }while(op!=4);  

}



void pause()
{
    printf("\n\nPress ENTER to continue\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    }



void add()
{
    printf("\tADD THE NAMES\n\n");

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Name in [%i]: ", i);
        scanf(" %[^\n]", name[i]);
        }

        pause();
    }   



void show_remove()
{
    int i,j,x;

    for(i=0; i<5-1; i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1; j<5; j++)
            {
            x=strcmp(name[i], name[j]);
            if(x>0)
            {
                strcpy(aux, name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], aux);                       

                }
                }
            }


    printf("\tADDED NAMES\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName in [%i]: %s", i, name[i]);
        }


        printf("\n\n'1' yes, '0' no.");
        printf("\nDo you want to delete an element from array? 1/0:");
        scanf(" %i", &op);

        if(op==1)
        {
        printf("\n\nAdd the index that you wish to delete: ");
    scanf(" %i", &position);



    if(position>=5)
    {
        printf("Can't be deleted!");
        }


    else
    {
    for(i=position; i<5-1; i++)
    {
            x=strcmp(name[i], name[i+1]);
            if(x<0)
            {
                strcpy(name[i], name[i+1]);
                }
            }


printf("\nArray after the elimination: \n");
for(i=0; i<5-1; i++)
{
    printf("\nElementsof the array [%i]: %s", i, name[i]);
        }
        pause();
        }
    }



    else
    {   
    pause();
        }

    }



void show()
{
    printf("\tADDES NAMES\n\n");
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
        printf("\nElements of the array [%i]: %s", i, name[i]);
            }
        }
        pause();


    }
```

Comment: _Minimal_ example, ok?

Comment: `5-1` you do know that is the same as `4`? :-)

Comment: Your `show` function always prints 5 names. You need it to print less names if you remove any. Use a variable to track the number of names

Comment: Observe my edit and feel embarassed because it's so **much** more readable than your original question, please.

Comment: or blank out the old names

Comment: @kaylum, the` x>0` check is correct for sorting the names.  The question is why are you sorting the names every time you call remove?

Answer (score 2):

It repeats the last position because that's exactly what you are telling it to  do.  You are deleting by copying all the elements after the deleted one down one position.  But you leave the original copy in the last slot.  You need to fill it with an empty string.  Or only list 4 slots, as @kevin suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get more information on the `strcmp` library function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

You can also provide some user defined string to depict end is reached.

OR

You should **decrement the size as per the deletion** so that the last is not left vacated for any junk value/deleted value to reoccur.
Doing so will eliminate the chance of getting equal string comparison go undetected and will make your program function properly.

Comment: can u give me an example please?